# Magento 2: How to run CLI command on admin store (storeId:0)?

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, rest-api, cli, store-id

I have a multi-store setup with Magento 2.1.7 CE on the domain a, domain b, domain c. I want to apply images to some products programmatically. When I make an API call on any domain with the "all" path:

(`index.php/rest/**all**/V1/my/apply/images`. instead of `index.php/rest/V1/my/apply/images`)

The store is 0 - that's what I want. The api calls a helper method in this case.

But I do not want to call the REST API but do this by CLI to avoid timeouts. So I wrote a command and this is calling the same helper method as the REST API call does. So I wonder how to set the store. It's running the default store only.

Using the `storeManager->setCurrentStore(0)` before calling the helper method doesn't have any effects.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`, the method `setCurrentStore` expects a string as single argument, but when using a string, this doesn't work either.

But it works when using `\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` as an argument (`$this->_storeManager` is the injected `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in this example):

```
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($this->_storeManager->getStore(0));
```