# Magento 2.3 | How to get Website ID in Cron Class

Tags: magento2.3, cron, websites

I tried to retrieve it as:

```
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
```

and

```
$websiteId = (int)$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
```

But it returns null in cron class.

How to get website ID there?

Answer (score 1):

The cron is run on an Application level rather than a Website level. What i mean by that is, a single crontask needs to be able to handle all website / store views.

So you can either add an entry into the system config where you can set a website id and pull that into the crontask. Or iterate all the websites likes so.

```php
$websites = $this->storeManager->getWebsites();
foreach($websites as $id => $website) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set current store in the cron task itself

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188727/70343

```
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($this->_storeManager->getStore(0));
```

Then you can retrieve it